# Grails Spring Security integration with WebSphere Global Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, websphere, spring-ldap

I recently developed a Grails application which uses Spring LDAP and Spring Security for authentication using LDAP. Its working great. But now I am trying to make it work with WebSphere 8.5 Application global security settings.

I have configured WebSphere Global Security with LDAP information and test connection and login works with LDAP users. But now I want to integrate the same with Grails.

I tried few options but it's not really going anywhere and did not find much information online.

Comment: If you can get this working with Spring Security outside of Grails (it's more likely that this has been done with traditional Spring & Spring Security) I can help you to get it working in Grails with the plugin.

Comment: Thanks Burt for quick response. The one i tried was configuring grails config.groovy file to have all the required parameters for connecting to LDAP. What i am looking for is a way to call container j_security_check which can authenticate the LDAP user and then redirecting to grails controller. Let me know if this can be achieved.